# Diffence between Menu and Context Menu and Creating steps of these

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

What is the difference between Menu and Context Menu? How  they are  creating in android, menu including edit, delete, copy and many other option in android. here, by using list items during creating context menu and menu.

Comment: Didn't you try to go through the www.android.com , you can easily find example and documentation for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of Menus

- Option Menu  (If you click on Hardware Menu button your option menu will come into play)
- Context Menu (If you long click on any list item in list view (your context menu will come into play we have to register context menu to work)
- SubMenu